# Can I get Last Digit of an Integer in Python

Tags: python, function, split, integer, typeerror

I am Trying to Find the Last Digit of my Integer. but unable to find it.

**`Note -` I am Using .split() in my Working Dish.**

```
# cooking my dish here

x = str(input())

letters = ""
words = x.split()

for word in words:
    letters += word[0]
    a = int(word(0) + word[-1])
    print(a)
```

I want to Wrap up all the things with this Error.

```
21
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\testererterset.py", line 9, in <module>
    a = int(word(0) + word[-1])
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>>>
```

I need serious help. You can Also Share Your code below if you want me to Understand Greatly.
**Till then zeez!**

Comment: `word(0)` -> `word[0]`

Comment: you are using circular brackets to get the first character : a = int(word(0) + word[-1]) this is wrong, you need to write this as  : a = int(word[0] + word[-1])

Answer (score 1):

```
word(0)
```

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

```
word[0]
```

Should work.

Comment: Peter, Thanks for your Response. Thanks for that Quickness too. but when I am running the same code. by writing a number in input it is not returning my number in listed form although I have mentioned in the above code that I am Inputting as a String and Returning as an Integer. but that Code is Just Returning The Same Number that I added in Input. Can I seek Help? from You?

Comment: Consider this [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and especially provide your input and the expected output.